# an error was encountered registering for push notifications please try again

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-arc

I am using [ARC Welder](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc)
I am trying to install an app that uses push notifications.

It gives me this error.

`An error was encountered registering for push notifications please try again`

This is the app I am trying to run. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.notafy.notafy&hl=en

I guess this might be some thing I need to install or add to have notifications working.

Comment: Any code? What have you tried to adapt your app for ARC Welder? Have you followed instruction to port the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This app probably uses [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) (GCM) for push notifications.

ARC Welder does not contain Google Play Services, which is a requisite for using GCM. Because of that, the app lacks an integral part of itself. A good idea for the developer would be some homebrew mechanism for getting notifications (not push) to be used when the platform does not have Play Services.